# Could not convert '{1, 2 ,3, 4, 5, 6}' to list<int> C++?

Tags: c++, list, vector, int

I am new to this and I'm doing some research on lists, vectors etc.

> [Error] in C++98 'val' must be initialized by constructor, not by '{...}'
>
> [Error] could not convert '{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}' from <'brace-enclosed initializer list'> to 'std::list'

The error comes from the line:

```
list<int> val = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
```

Is there any reason as to this happening or am I just missing the big picture? Any help will be appreciated, kindest regards!

Comment: Perhaps you're missing the fact that you might be using an old C++98 compiler (as mentioned in your error) that does not support current C++ standards, at least C++11, where braced initialization, of this fashion, was introduced?

Comment: Since your compiler is aware that this is a modern C++ feature (see the reference to C++98 in the error message) I'm guessing that your compile could support this feature if you picked the right compiler options.

Comment: `-std=c++11` missing on the compilation command line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`initializer_list` is C++ 11 feature, it might be possible it is not available in C++98( may the tool chain you are using ) which is giving this error.